# How to get typescript compiler to infer type of getDefaultMiddleware? Getting implicitly 'any' error

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I'm getting an error:

> Parameter 'getDefaultMiddleware' implicitly has an 'any' type.

My store code looks like this:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import uiStateReducer from './ui_state';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const rootReducer = {
  uiState: uiStateReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => {
    return getDefaultMiddleware.concat(logger)
  }
};

const store = configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer });
```

I've checked the Redux-Toolkit Github issues page for anyone who's having this issue (couldn't find anything) and all the code snippets of other issues showing the `(getDefaultMiddleware) => {` function do not explicitly type the `getDefaultMiddleware`. Can someone point me to how `getDefaultMiddleware` can be inferred?

Answer (score 0):

Redux middleware is added to the store when it is created, not as a reducer function. It seems that Typescript is reading this as a reducer function and letting you know the "state" argument isn't explicitly typed.

```
const rootReducer = {
  uiState: uiStateReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => { // <-- thinks this is a reducer function!
    return getDefaultMiddleware.concat(logger)
  }
};
```

See [middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#middleware)

> ### middleware
>
> A callback which will receive `getDefaultMiddleware` as its argument,
> and should return a middleware array.
>
> If this option is provided, it should return all the middleware
> functions you want added to the store. `configureStore` will
> automatically pass those to `applyMiddleware`.
>
> If not provided, `configureStore` will call `getDefaultMiddleware` and
> use the array of middleware functions it returns.
>
> For more details on how the `middleware` parameter works and the list
> of middleware that are added by default, see the
> [`getDefaultMiddleware` docs page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware).
>
> > **TUPLE**
> >
> > Typescript users are required to use a `Tuple` instance (if not using
> > a `getDefaultMiddleware` result, which is already a `Tuple`), for
> > better inference.
> >
> > ```
> > import { configureStore, Tuple } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
> >
> > configureStore({
> >   reducer: rootReducer,
> >   middleware: () => new Tuple(additionalMiddleware, logger),
> > })
> > ```
> >
> > Javascript-only users are free to use a plain array if preferred.

If using the `getDefaultMiddleware` function then the types are inferred more easily.

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import uiStateReducer from './ui_state';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const rootReducer = {
  uiState: uiStateReducer,
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware.concat(logger),
});
```

If Typescript users are just adding their own middleware then they ***must*** return a `Tuple`.

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import uiStateReducer from './ui_state';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

const rootReducer = {
  uiState: uiStateReducer,
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: () => new Tuple(logger),
});
```

Comment: Ohh I see! It's part of the configure store argument, not the reducer object. Makes so much sense, thanks